# Are JQuery Image galleries such as Lightbox free to commercial use?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Is Lightbox completely free even in commercial production?

Comment: "Lightbox" has become such a generic term that you should clarify *which one* exactly you're talking about. Also, just **read the licensing terms** which should always come with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the script [here](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox/lightbox.js), which I'm assuming is the lightbox you are referring to you can see in the comments:

> Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/
>     (basically, do anything you want, just leave my name and link)